# What's the meaning of 'Cronenbourg' in the Rick and Morty episode Rick Potion No. 9?

Tags: dialogue, rick-and-morty

Near the end of the episode *Rick Potion No. 9*,  both Rick and Morty repeatedly refer to their situation with the word *Cronenbourg*. To be more specific:

> When Rick turns almost everyone on Earth into hideously deformed mutants by modifying their genes *en masse*, Morty accuses him of "...creating a bunch of Cronenbourgs."

The only Cronenbourg I know of (or could find) is a place in France (and the eponymous brewery), and I don't think it's known for... that. So what's their meaning?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's **[Cronenberg](http://rickandmorty.wikia.com/wiki/Cronenbergs)**, named after director [David Cronenberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cronenberg).

> The word/name Cronenberg is a reference to Canadian filmmaker, screenwriter, actor, and director David Cronenberg. This is due to the fact that Cronenberg is one of the originators of the "body horror" genre in which the style of filmmaking explores people's fears of bodily transformation and infection.

Here are some examples from his films:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: Wow (and... urk)! Sure enough, the [Wikipedia entry on his film *Shivers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivers_(film)#In_popular_culture) has: 'The Rick and Morty episode "Rick Potion No. 9" from season one of the series is loosely premised on Cronenberg's Shivers, and the creatures in the episode are even called "Cronenbergs" as a sort of homage.'

Comment: Is the last picture from Shivers?

Comment: @beppe9000 No, it's from *Naked Lunch*.